# How to use sub-queries in select clause with sub-queries in from clause

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I try to query but got error tt.comp is not valid in context.

I think sub-queries#1(select clause) can't access a sub-queries#2(from clause) or sub-queries#1 execute before sub-queries#2.

```
SELECT grp1
      ,(select count(distinct tt.comp) as comp
        from t as tt
        where tt.lamp = 1
        and tt.pop = t.pop)
FROM (select ......) as t group by grp1
```

How to resolve that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You typically either use correlated subqueries, OR do a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are referring the same table in sub-query, You can simply use CASE statement I guess -

```
 SELECT grp1,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lamp = 1 THEN tt.comp END) AS COMP
FROM (select ......) as t
GROUP BY grp1
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff, Thanks.